# Parse multiple tags in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser at the same time

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to save two different tags content in two different variable in the same "foreach" loop, but I get `parse error` in the following:

```
foreach( $days -> find('td[!width]') as $schedule) && ($days -> find('a') as $title ) {
        echo "<div class=\"movie_name\">"
        .$title->plaintext."</div> - <div class=\"movie_schedule\">"
        .$schedule->plaintext."</div>\n";
}
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

*** Edit ***

I solved the problem separating the loop in two separate ones, like this:

```
    $movie_titles = array();
    foreach($days -> find('a') as $title) {
        $movie_titles[] = $title->plaintext;
    }
    $counter = 0;
    foreach( $days -> find('td[!width]') as $schedule) {
        echo "<div class=\"movie_name\">"
        .$movie_titles[$counter]
        ."</div> - <div class=\"movie_schedule\">"
        .$schedule->plaintext."</div>\n";
        $counter = $counter + 1;
    }
```

Not very elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: Share the exact error message you get instead of letting the community guess.

Comment: I was getting exactly `parse error` as error.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` doesn't work this way. Only

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // ...
}
```

You have to use two loops or totally different approach (depends on your task).

I.e.

```
foreach ($days->find('td[!width]') as $schedule) {
    foreach ($days->find('a') as $title) {
        echo "<div class=\"movie_name\">"
            . $title->plaintext."</div> - <div class=\"movie_schedule\">"
            . $schedule->plaintext."</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already figured it out, and made two separate loops.